# JS: How do create prototypes when creating factory functions rather than classes?

Tags: javascript, factory

If I am creating a factory function, how would I create a prototype to avoid each instance of the new object inheriting each property?

```
    function Person(name) {
        function indentify() {
           return "I am " + name
        }

        return Object.freeze({
            name,
            indentify

        })

    }
```

If I want to create a Person object without having all of them contain identify, can I do this with factory functions or do I have to use the Class syntax?

Comment: Did you mean "without having all of them *create a new* identify"?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to continue using a factory function and avoid the `new` operator, you can use [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) to create objects with a certain prototype:

```
const personProto = {
    identify() {
        return "I am " + this.name; // needs to access the property of course, there's no closure
    }
};
function Person(name) {
    return Object.freeze(Object.assign(Object.create(personProto), {name}));
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Bergi .  This seems like a lot to achieve this, right?  Is this why there is an appeal of Class syntax?

Comment: @Curly No, not really. `class` syntax doesn't create frozen instances, so no `Object.freeze`, and you have to create properties through assignment not with object literal syntax, so no `Object.assign` :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
function Person(name) {

  this.name = name;

}

Person.prototype.indentify = function() {
  return "I am " + this.name
}
```

off-topic, I guess you were looking for the word `identify` ?

Comment: Hey @Evert .  I get an error when using that code and setting l`et me = Person("Albert")`     then  `me.identify()` throws an error saying cannot read property of undefined

Comment: @Curly you are supposed to call `const me = new Person('Albert')`;.

Comment: I thought `new` was not needed for factory functions? `A factory function is any function which is not a class or constructor that returns a (presumably new) object. In JavaScript, any function can return an object. When it does so without the new keyword, it’s a factory function.` -- https://medium.com/javascript-scene/javascript-factory-functions-with-es6-4d224591a8b1

Comment: @Curly you *can* use new with factory functions. In this example though, you don't need factory function at all

Answer (score 0):

I would make constructor function and add identify to prototype like so:

```
function Person(name) {

    this.name = name; 
    Object.freeze(this)

}

Person.prototype.indentify = function() {
       return "I am " + this.name
}
```

And create a new person like so

```
var person = new Person('John')
```

Answer (score 0):

How about composing functionality onto person. An example could be something like this:

```js
const createPerson = (name) => ({ name })
const withIdentify = (person) => ({ ...person, identify: () => `I am ${person.name}` }) 

let person = createPerson('Chris')

console.log(person) // { name: 'Chris' }

person = withIdentify(person); 

console.log(person) // { name: 'Chris', identify: f }

console.log(person.identify()) // 'I am Chris'
```

You could even use partial execution to clean up the `withIdentify` function if you decided.